# Roots of the equation $(1-4x)^4+32x^4=\frac{1}{27}​$

Tags: inequality, roots, binomial-theorem, holder-inequality

find all real roots of the equation $(1-4x)^4+32x^4=\dfrac{1}{27}​$

i try to use binomial expansion and am-gm inequality but i don't know how to do next.

Comment: What did you do after expanding the binomial?  Did you test for rational roots?  (The am-gm inequality has nothing to do with this problem.)

Comment: @saulspatz Actually, AMGM shows that inequality holds only if $x = \frac{1}{6}$, so it can be used.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks for pointing that out.  I feel stupid.

Comment: @saulspatz Don't be. That's one of my [favorite ways of applying AM-GM to equalities](https://brilliant.org/wiki/applying-the-arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean/#given-an-equation-use-am-gm-to-determine-extra-conditions). It creeps up unexpectedly (unless you already realize that it's a "minimum/maximum" situation.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks again.  I meant, in all these years, this application of AM_GM has never occurred to me, and when it was suggested, I just dismissed it out of hand.   That *was* dumb.

Answer (score 6):

By curiosity, let us find the minimum of the LHS.

From the derivative, we solve

$$(1-4x)^3=8x^3$$ or $$1-4x=2x$$ so that there is a single local minimum at

$$x=\frac16$$ and $$f(x)=\frac1{81}+\frac2{81}\ !$$

Comment: SHAZAM!  How did you think of that?

Comment: @saulspatz: the small constant $\dfrac1{27}$ was suspect and I thought it was worth to check whether a real solution existed at all. In case yes, the minimum would have given an estimate anyway.

Answer (score 3):

First, we can rewrite the left hand side of your equation as:
$$\text{LHS} \stackrel{def}{=}(1-4x)^4 + (2x)^4 + (2x)^4$$

Notice $(1-4x) + (2x) + (2x) = 1$ and the map $t \mapsto t^4$ is strictly convex.
By [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality), we have
$$\text{LHS} \ge 3\left[\frac{(1-4x)+(2x)+(2x)}{3}\right]^4 = \frac1{27}$$
and the equality is reached when and only when $2x = 1-4x$.

This implies your original equation has one (and only one) real solution: $x = \frac16$.

Comment: I'm sure I'm being dense, but could you please explain how you apply Jensen's inequality here?  (There's a typo, obviously, but that's not what I'm taking about.  I just can't follow what you did.)

Comment: @saulspatz Jensen's inequality states that if $f(x)$ is convex, then $\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n f(t_k) \ge f(\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n t_k)$. Now take $f(t) = t^4, n = 3$ with $t_1 = 1-4x, t_2 = t_3 = 2x$, you get
$$\text{LHS} = 3\cdot\frac13\sum_{k=1}^3 f(t_k) \ge 3f\left(\frac13\sum_{k=1}^n t_k\right) = 3f\left(\frac13\right) = \frac1{27}$$

Comment: I see now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly there are no solutions if $ x > \frac{1}{4}$ or $ x < 0$. So, we may apply the power mean inequality to $ 1-4x, 2x, 2x$.

$$\sqrt[4]{\frac{( 1- 4x)^ 4 + (2x)^4 + (2x)^4 }{3}}\geq   \frac{ (1-4x) + 2x + 2x } { 3} =  \frac{1}{3} $$

This tells us that $( 1- 4x)^ 4 + 32x^4 \geq \frac{1}{27}$.

Equality holds iff $ 1 -4x = 2x = 2x$, or that $ x = \frac{1}{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x<0$ so
$$(1-4x)^4+32x^4>1>\frac{1}{27}.$$
If $x>\frac{1}{4}$ so
$$(1-4x)^4+32x^4>32\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^4>\frac{1}{27}.$$
Id est, it's enough to solve our equation for $x\in\left[0,\frac{1}{4}\right]$.

But in this case by Holder we obtain:
$$(1-4x)^4+32x^4=\frac{1}{27}(1+2)^3((1-4x)^4+2(2x)^4)\geq\frac{1}{27}(1-4x+2\cdot2x)^4=\frac{1}{27}.$$
But we have equality and the equality in Holder occurs for $(1,2)||((1-4x)^4,32x^4)$ only,

which gives
$$1-4x=2x$$ or $$x=\frac{1}{6}.$$